# WildFly naming subsystem: how to bind to a java.util.Properties object

Tags: wildfly, jndi

I intend to define a JNDI propery of the type `java.util.Properties` in the WildFly application server to read it from my application.

As described [in the an older WildFly documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Global%20Bindings%20Configuration.html) one can create a global binding of the type object-factory. In the example is an optional `environment` tag to hold multiple key/value pairs. That would map exactly my desire to get a `java.util.Properties` when reading a JNDI resource.

The question is weather there is already an implementiation of `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` to create a `java.util.Properties` object out of an object-factory binding or do I need to implement it myself and install it as a separate module (like it is described at [mastertheboss.com/...](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-configuration/jboss-jndi-binding-configuration/))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just implemented it mysef.

```
package com.myorg.wildfly.objectfactory;

...

public class WildFlyPropertiesObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory
{
  @Override
  public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable environment) throws Exception 
  {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    if(environment != null)
    {
      Set<?> keySet = environment.keySet();
      for(Object key : keySet)
      {
        p.put(key, environment.get(key));
      }  
    }
    return p;
  }
}
```

- Clean&Build this single class into a JAR file *wildfly-properties-objetfactory.jar*
- Add a module via jboss-cli.sh

  `module add --name=my.jndi.propertyreader --resource=wildfly-properties-objetfactory.jar --dependencies=javax.api`
- Create a naming binding via jboss-cli.sh

  `/subsystem=nameing/binding=java\:\/my_super_cool_jndi_name:add(binding-type=object-factory, module=my.jndi.propertyreader, class=com.myorg.wildfly.objectfactory.WildFlyPropertiesObjectFactory, environment=[key1=value1, key2=value2])`

And in my application I can access it in an CDI bean via

```
public void test() {
  Properties p = (Properties) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/my_super_cool_jndi_name");
  System.out.printf("Properties: %s%n", p);
}
```

Or as shown in [the mentioned link](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-configuration/jboss-jndi-binding-configuration/) inject it as a direct dependency `@Resource(lookup = "java:/my_super_cool_jndi_name") Properties p;`

Works as a charm.